# sending stored javascript variables using href to a new url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im trying to get a stored variable that came in a url to be used as a variable with href.

The code I have so far is:

```
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
    var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
    if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
        return KeyValuePair[1];
    }
}
```

}

And this works

http://www.somesite.com/?title=1254&keyphrase=phase1
arrives to the page with the script and it does store the values for title and keyphrase.

What Im trying to do is to build a href that in the end has a link like this:

http://www.anewsite.com/1254/

The domain will never change - only the variable at the end.
Is this possible ?
Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: yes, it's possible. just build a new string: `var url = 'http://' + hostname + '/' + value_you_want`

Comment: Thank you! As you can gather Im new to JS so I appreciate your reply.  Best.